# Executing python file stored in oracle clob field

Tags: python, oracle

is there way to execute python2 file that is stored in oracle clob field.

I have tried something like this

```
cur.execute("""SELECT pyfile FROM dual """)
```

`printout = cur.fetchone()`

```
exec str(printout[0])
```

i get error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

should it work somehow?

Comment: can you give the value of str(printout[0])?

Comment: Are you aware of possible vulnerabilities?

Comment: Yes im aware security vulnerabilities ,  lets say str(printout[0]) value is var = 1+4 and it works. But if i add second line then it breaks with syntax error. It looks like it has something to do with line ending

Comment: Im adding it from text box and it is formatted correctly even if i reload it from database or print it out into logger.

Comment: The cause of the syntax error depends upon the value of `printout[0]`. Please copy-paste (don't summarize, don't retype) an exact error message and stack trace into your question. Copy-paste the exact result of `print repr(printout[0])`.